# How can I get direct access to a QWidget in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qtableview

I know you can insert a QWidget (like QLineEdit) into a tableview.

For Example:

```
QSortFilterProxyModel *m = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
ui -> tblView -> setIndexWidget(m -> index(0, 0), new QLineEdit); // works fine

//another option
QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit;
ui -> TblDataLeagues -> setIndexWidget(m -> index(i, 0), le); //also works; advantage is, you can setup the QLineEdit before you add it into the tableview
```

Now, in cell or better at index 0, 0 you have a QLineEdit.
How can I direct adress the widget?
In the way that I can use the functions of QLineEdit.
Or is it possible to read out the value directly from the cell?

Like this:

```
ui -> tblView -> indexWidget(m -> index(0, 0) ) -> text(); //no member named `text` in `QWidget`
```

You may want to read out the current or modified text from this QLineEdit.

Comment: use `qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(ui -> tblView -> indexWidget(m -> index(0, 0) )) -> text();`

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe it would never have occurred to me. Thanks for the quick help. Great community here.

Comment: mmm. you should review your OOP concepts

Comment: I think I know what you mean. The lines with "QSortFilterProxyModel" and "QLineEdit". I have seen this in the Qt documentation and have taken over unreflected for now. In my project I will improve this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, this function returns generally a `QWidget` to fit any subtype in the table. So, you need to apply casting for the retrieved object using the generic `qobject_cast<Target>` if you're sure of the type at this index.

Comment: Yes, And during my research I have found the following in the docu: "All Qt widgets inherit QObject. The convenience function isWidgetType() returns whether an object is actually a widget. It is much faster than qobject_cast<QWidget *>(obj) or obj->inherits("QWidget")." Very interesting. Does that mean I can apply casting with the function "isWidgetType()" ?

Comment: [`isWidgetType()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#isWidgetType) won't be helpful because `indexWidget()` actually returns a `QWidget`. What you really need is casting to your subclass to be able to access its functions.